# Launch google play store if app is not installed

Tags: android, android-webview, deep-linking, android-dialogfragment

Currently, I want to Open this link and if the application is not installed need it to navigate to google play. Following is the link I am trying to open.

> intent:qoo10sg://moveTab?index=2&url=https%3A%2F%2Fm.qoo10.my%2Fgmkt.inc%2FMobile%2FDeal%2FTimeSale.aspx%3Fcix%3D0%26__da_seqno%3D39213891#Intent;package=net.giosis.shopping.sg;end;

I want it to launch to app store from this URL is it possible ?

Comment: it is not possible AFAIK

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko even I tried this not working 
                                Intent intente = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));


                                String title = "Complete Action Using";

                                Intent chooser = intente.createChooser(intent, title);
                                startActivity(chooser);

Comment: pseudocode: if user has qoo10sg app installed: launch that intent url, if not, open play store that links to the package.

Comment: Try out Firebase dynamic links, they're meant to serve this exact purpose. They're also free to use

Comment: @Kushan Thanks dude I am planning to use Dynamic links for another feature in our app. Thanks for the mention.

Comment: Sure man no problem :)

Answer (score 3):

To accomplish this, you would need to perform a javascript redirect. I would host a web page at any url you'd like i.e. `yourdomain.com/checkForApp` and have some simple redirects.

Try the link, if it fails use Javascript redirect to the play store or app store.

```
setTimeout(function appNotInstalled() {
    window.location.replace("http://play.google.com/store");
}, 100);
window.location.replace("intent:qoo10sg://moveTab?index=2&url=https%3A%2F%2Fm.qoo10.my%2Fgmkt.inc%2FMobile%2FDeal%2FTimeSale.aspx%3Fcix%3D0%26__da_seqno%3D39213891#Intent;package=net.giosis.shopping.sg;end;");
```

Otherwise, [Branch](http://docs.branch.io) does this already within their SDK so you don't have to worry about building this out.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!openApp(MainActivity.this, "com.package")) {
    launchPlayStoreWithAppPackage(MainActivity.this, "com.pagkage");
}
/**
 * Open another app.
 *
 * @param context     current Context, like Activity, App, or Service
 * @param packageName the full package name of the app to open
 * @return true if likely successful, false if unsuccessful
 */
public static boolean openApp(Context context, String packageName) {
    PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
    try {
        Intent i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
        if (i == null) {
            return false;
            //throw new ActivityNotFoundException();
        }
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        context.startActivity(i);
        return true;
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * Open another app.
 *
 * @param context     current Context, like Activity, App, or Service
 * @param packageName the full package name of the app to open
 */
public static void launchPlayStoreWithAppPackage(Context context, String packageName) {
    Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + packageName));
    context.startActivity(i);
}
```